# CPU usage of R Session from windows performance monitor or Resource Monitor

Tags: r, windows, system, admin

How can I obtain the data of CPU usage of R Session from windows performance monitor or Resource Monitor between two time points as csv file in Windows
[image: Resource Monitor image]

Comment: One possibility is to right-click on the data, save data under `.csv` format. You could then  use `read.csv` to analyze the data into R